# Drupal 7: Hook for Node processing before page loaded

Tags: drupal-7, hook, nodes

I am in Drupal 7 and want to do some side processing, i.e. neither to affect the fields nor the themeing, on a node, before the node's page is rendered. In other words, I want to implement in a custom module an 'appropriate hook' so that I can pick-up node's info. Again the implementing function I want to be executed in .module file rather than in template.php.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7

Probably you should have a look at hook_node_view.

Comment: hook_node_view is how I would do this too as you have access to the node object before any rendering is done.